# R-Shiny Leaflet Right-Click Context Menu

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I got a R-Shiny app and a leaflet map in my UI output. I want to setup something where I can right click on the map and it opens a context menu on cursor coordinates, where I can select icons and input text. This will allow me to place custom markers on the map and name them.

```
observeEvent(input$map_right_click, {
showCustomMarkerMenu(location = (input$map_click$lat, input$map_click$lng)) //sample
addMarkers(lat = input$map_click$lat, lng = input$map_click$lng)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve right clicks with [`htmlwidgets::onRender`](https://rdrr.io/cran/htmlwidgets/man/onRender.html) and [`Shiny.setInputValue`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicating-with-js.html). With `htmlwidgets::onRender` its possible to retrieve the leaflet map instance, which you need to get the coordinates of the click. Next with `Shiny.setInputValue` you send the coordinates to your shiny module or application and trigger a change event of the input which you observe with `observeEvent`.

```
leaflet::leaflet() %>% 
leaflet::addTiles() %>%
htmlwidgets::onRender("
    function(el,x) {
        map = this;
        map.on('contextmenu', function(e) {
        var coords = {lng: e.latlng.lng, lat: e.latlng.lat}
        Shiny.setInputValue('map_right_click', coords);
    });
    }
")

shiny::observeEvent(input$map_right_click, {
    output$myLng<- renderText({ input$map_right_click$lng })
})
```